# Discord.js Move members to different voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm trying to make a command that, when said, provided with a mention and the name of a Voice Channel, moves the member you mentioned to that Voice Channel. I've done a bit of research on this but still can't get it work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('../config.json');

exports.run = function(client, message) {

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();      

if (command === 'move') {
  const mem = message.mentions.members.first()
  const vc = args.join(" ")
  const chan = client.channels.find("name", vc)
    mem.setVoiceChannel(chan)
      .then(() => console.log(`Moved ${mem.displayName} to ${chan}`))
  .catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

Right now, when I try the command, using, let's just say, the Voice Channel "Music" (so, "d!move [mention] Music"), it returns "Moved [member] to null" to the console, and of course, doesn't move the member. It seems to find the member I mentioned just fine, but can't find the Voice Channel. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the mentioned user in a voice channel already?

Comment: Yeah, they are.

Comment: Could you try moving the user to a channel using the ID? something like `const chan = client.channels.get('someID')` and then move the user to that channel?

Comment: Tried it and it worked, with the code you gave. It moved the member from the General VC to the Music VC. Returned "Moved AlphaPolarBear1 to <#430469794114830336>" to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have the answer, so you are using `d!move [mention] Music` to move the user. After that you split into different arguments to handle it better, to something like this: `["move", "<@someID>", "Music"]`. Then you remove the first one that its the command with slice, and you get `["<@someID>", "Music"]`.
Then when you wanna find the channel name you join the array with spaces to get the channel name. Problem is you still have the mention there. So it will stay `<@someID> Music`, and it is trying to find a channel with that name.
You probably need to remove the first argument of the array the same way you did with the command, and then join it, or make a new array with only the name of the channel.